# Spring Data Mongo | Dynamic Collection name failing with @Query methods

Tags: spring-data-mongodb

Consider a simple domain class:-

```
@Document(collection = "#{T(demo.TenantGenerator).tenant()}Employee")
public class Employee  implements Serializable{

    /**
     * serialVersionUID
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6236812201549032402L;

    @Id
    private String id;

    protected String name;

    /**
     * @return the name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * @param name the name to set
     */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


}
```

Here I have configured dynamic collection name using SpEL targeting a static method:-

```
public class TenantGenerator {

    public static String tenant = "";

    public static final String tenant(){
        return tenant;
    }
}
```

This is how my repository interface looks like:-

```
public interface EmployeeRepository extends MongoRepository<Employee,String> {

    @Query(value="{'name':?0}")
    public List<Employee> someMethod(String id);
}
```

My test code:-

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
public class ApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeRepository repo;

    @Autowired
    private MongoTemplate template;

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {

        // Set the collection with ABC
        TenantGenerator.tenant = "ABC";

        Employee e = new Employee();
        e.setName("test");

        repo.save(e);

        Employee ee = new Employee();
        e.setName("test");

        repo.save(ee);


        List<Employee> findAll = repo.findAll();
        System.out.println(findAll.size());

        Employee eee = new Employee();
        e.setName("test");


        template.save(eee,"customercoll");

        System.out.println(repo.someMethod("test"));

        //Set collection name with XYZ
        TenantGenerator.tenant = "XYZ";

        System.out.println(repo.someMethod("test")); // PROBLEM  this should try to get from XYZ. But instead tries to fetch from ABC itself
        System.out.println(repo.findAll());

    }

}
```

### PROBLEM

The collection name is correctly picked at run time except case when I a method in my repository that has @Query annotation.

While trying to debug the Spring Data Mongo code , I found that for @Query annotated methods,`org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.MongoQueryMethod`  caches the collection information inside it in property `org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.MongoQueryMethod.metadata`.

So while trying to get `org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.MongoQueryMethod.getEntityInformation()` during query execution, collection name is not fetched using the SpEL the second time.

Relavant piece of code:-

```
@Override
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public MongoEntityMetadata<?> getEntityInformation() {

    if (metadata == null) { // !!!THIS IS PROBLEM FOR ME!!!!

        Class<?> returnedObjectType = getReturnedObjectType();
        Class<?> domainClass = getDomainClass();

        MongoPersistentEntity<?> returnedEntity = mappingContext.getPersistentEntity(getReturnedObjectType());
        MongoPersistentEntity<?> managedEntity = mappingContext.getPersistentEntity(domainClass);
        returnedEntity = returnedEntity == null ? managedEntity : returnedEntity;
        MongoPersistentEntity<?> collectionEntity = domainClass.isAssignableFrom(returnedObjectType) ? returnedEntity
                : managedEntity;

        this.metadata = new SimpleMongoEntityMetadata<Object>((Class<Object>) returnedEntity.getType(),
                collectionEntity.getCollection());
    }

    return this.metadata;
}
```

### WHAT I WANT

How can I pick collection name at run time even for the @Query annotated repository methods?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're running [into this](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1043) issue which has been fixed recently, was just released in Spring Data MongoDB 1.7 M1 and is scheduled to be in to-be-released 1.6.2 and 1.5.5. Feel free to give the milestones a spin.